# Match grouped list elements with regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm sure this question has been asked before, but I'm unable to find it.

I have a bunch of list elements like so:

```
<li class="list-item">aewfaffjpiowfj: apeifjeawpfioj</li>
<li class="list-item">aewfaffjpiowfj: apeifjeawpfioj</li>
<li class="list-item">aewfaffjpiowfj: apeifjeawpfioj</li>
<li class="list-item">aewfaffjpiowfj: apeifjeawpfioj</li>
<br><br>

sample text
<li class="list-item">aewfaffjpiowfj: apeifjeawpfioj</li>
<li class="list-item">aewfaffjpiowfj: apeifjeawpfioj</li>

more text
<li class="list-item">aewfaffjpiowfj: apeifjeawpfioj</li>
```

I want to wrap each group in a `<ul></ul>` element. How do I do that?

This is what I've tried, but it only matches the individual elements:
`/<li [^>]*>.*<\/li>/g`

https://regex101.com/r/KXEkJz/1

And if I do `/<li [^>]*>[\s\S]*<\/li>/g`, it produces one giant match.

Comment: You said you want to wrap each "group" in a `<ul>`.  Do you consider them a group if there is only one line break between them?  What makes it a group?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @snollygolly yes, any `<li>` element that follows with another `<li>` element are considered part of the same group. If there are line breaks, newlines, or other text, then that would serve as the boundary for the groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to group them by new lines, try something like this:

`(<li [^>]*>.*<\/li>\n?)+`

The only difference between it and yours is that it tries to capture multiple `<li>` objects and doesn't mind if there is a new line.  If there's a new line followed by something different though, it stops matching.

Comment: Goodness. I can't believe I overlooked this simple answer. Thank you!

Comment: For future viewers, I had to wrap the solution in one more layer `/((?:<li [^>]*>.*<\/li>\n?)+)/g` before being able to do `<ul>$1</ul>`.